# JUnit test cleanup for single method

Tags: java, junit

I have a JUnit test class with a number of different test cases. One of these test cases has bit different test setup and cleanup than the other ones. What is the best way to do test cleanup in such scenario? Extract test case into separate class and use standard @Before and @After annotations?

Comment: That would definitely be one way to go. Could you share some code so we have a concrete example?

Comment: It's basically about adding some entries to DB in setup and removing these entries in cleanup. My only concern is that number of test classes will grow. As an alternative I thought about having setup and cleanup as a part of the test case with cleanup in finally block.

Comment: As an alternative to "cleanup" you can also add the records on the beginning of the test itselft and enclose everything in a transaction, and in the finally block you rollback the transaction

Answer (score 1):

Make a subclass with only that test, write custom @Before and @After methods calling super ones if needed.